# Custom dynamic popover using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a pure JavaScript function (setPopOver) as a coding exercise for my college course that receives a title and content and generates popover when hovering over any HTML element. I've worked with JS with Angular before, but no pure JS, so I'm kinda stuck.

The API for using this should be:

```
$(SOME_HTML_ELEMENT).setPopOver(title, content);
```

How am I suppose to "inject" a new function to a DOM node to use ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, you can add custom function to jquery object

```
$.fn.setPopOver = function(title, content) {
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            // add popup element here
        }, 
        function() {
            // remove popup element here
        }
    )
}
```